# How can I reload at once all the Google Chrome extensions that crashed?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

From time to time, some Google Chrome extensions crash.

[image]

Is it possible to reload at once all the Google Chrome extensions that  crashed, e.g. with a keyboard shortcut or pressing on some button?

I don't want to have to restart Google Chrome. It is tedious to restart each crashed  Google Chrome extensions one by one.

[image]

I use Google Chrome on Windows.